# How to organize Hadoop's generate jars with Maven

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I used Maven to build the Hadoop source successfully. However, the resulting jars are scattered in every `target` folder in each modules. When I looked at the original Hadoop binary files, all jars are well organized in a single folder. Moreover, there are other files besides jars in stable release, which I cannot find in my Maven compilation result.

How can I build Hadoop to obtain binaries with that kind of organization?

I guess I am lack of some very basic knowledge about commercial software production, since I am always writing code for research purpose. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [Build instructions for Hadoop](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/BUILDING.txt) you'll find a distribution Maven instruction. Try that, and it should generate a distribution like the one you see when you downloaded the binaries.

> Build distribution        : mvn package [-Pdist][-Pdocs][-Psrc][-Pnative][-Dtar]

Comment: Thanks! I guess "distribution" is the right term I am looking for!